# SQLITE: Bulk insert or replace (upsert)

Tags: python, sqlite, upsert

I have an application that inserts (or replaces) records with a unique key into a SQLite database table.
It is expected to do about 1500 records per second but it's slower than this due to performance issues.

Currently I'm doing it as such (in Python):

```
for item in items:
    CONN.execute("INSERT OR REPLACE INTO ITEMS (ITEM_ID) VALUES ("+item['itemId']+")")
```

What I would like is a bulk insert or replace to improve performance.

I know there is a way to do bulk inserts:
[Is it possible to insert multiple rows at a time in an SQLite database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609637/is-it-possible-to-insert-multiple-rows-at-a-time-in-an-sqlite-database)

But is there a way to do bulk insert or replace?
I know that insert or replace is NOT the same as upsert - that's OK.

Answer (score -2):

Try something like this

`INSERT OR REPLACE INTO items (id, link, added) VALUES (19122727, "https://instant.page/", COALESCE((SELECT added FROM items WHERE id = 19122727), 1549742777)),(19123506, "http://hades.mech.northwestern.edu/index.php/Modern_Robotics", COALESCE((SELECT added FROM items WHERE id = 19123506), 1549742777)),(19123352, "https://dendibakh.github.io/blog/2019/02/09/Top-Down-performance-analysis-methodology", COALESCE((SELECT added FROM items WHERE id = 19123352), 1549742777))`